# Help needed to recover Unsaved 'Notes' on Mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: snow-leopard, notes.app

I had written some notes on the phone with a client and Outlook crashes and lost my notes. They were indepth... and I am embarrassed about asking the client to run through all the information again... And I need for a meeting tomorrow.
Please, can anyone hayelp me (she asks hopefully)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the data is in a different folder than the app. I use a little app (on my Mac) that allows me to read the contents of iPhone data, grab photos, etc. It might work for you. Here's the [link](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/). Hope it helps.

Comment: Are bless you David you are a superstar... I will give it a go now;)...and cross everything!

Comment: Thank you for recognizing my talents. Wish that were true:) Anyway, let us know if this works or not.